# Is it possible to receive a downvote on an answer from a user with 1 rep point?

Tags: support

[This is my downvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224051/248519)

I realize it might not be a nice answer but the person who has down voted has only 1 reputation point.

What I have heard until now it's we need at least 125 reputation points to downvote any questions/answers.

The downvotes may have come from other users but I think his comment is indicating that it was him.

So my question is possible that a user with 1 rep point is capable of downvoting or am I missing something?

Comment: Konstantinos commented on the downvote, they didn't say they were the downvoter. And you're right, downvoting is a 125 rep privilege

Comment: the person who commented didn't downvote, he's expressing disagreement with the downvote

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the comment, he was not the downvoter.

Comment: Ohk i got it.I was bit confused and also was worried if it could really happen.

Comment: Please **DON'T** use code formatting to the link.

Comment: @RichardTingle, but wouldn't there be something else going on as well because you need 50 rep to comment on a question you didn't ask?

Comment: @PeterJ Thats an interesting point. I think I recall meta has an exception to that rule but I don't have the link to hand

Comment: @PeterJ The post was migrated from SO. The comment must have been made over there.

Comment: @All - Welcome to **Meta** Stack Overflow. Commenting requires only [1 reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) here.

Comment: @PeterJ Commenting is [1 rep requirement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on meta

Comment: @Bart The user in question only has 10 rep on SO, he must have done it here.

Comment: @3ventic, thanks I'd assumed it was the same as other sites.

Comment: @JasonC Reversed upvote that doesn't show, who knows. He must have had 15 rep at some point, if only briefly.

Comment: @Bart No. It was clearly hax, and we *need* to continue discussing this for no less than 50 more comments. Hold on, I'm going to start a Hangout for this.

Comment: Why I am down voted. Should a user with a question should not be allowed to say anything.

Comment: Enclined to agree, you researched the question, everything you believed was correct. Only the reading of the comment was wrong. For what it's worth +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misread what that person posted.

Nothing about what he said indicates that he is responsible for that down vote. He did not claim responsibility for it, he simply commented that he thought it was "surreal" (given the context) that somebody else did it.

Don't worry, his comment was a very poorly constructed sentence (if you could even call it that); if you're not fluent in reading English it is probably not an easy comment to figure out.